# Aligning checkboxes via inherited css?

Tags: html, css

I have a php page, which launches a popup window containing a form with checkboxes. The originating window includes an external stylesheet.

The form html for the popup window is:

```
<form name="statusForm" action="post.php=" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="Test">Test:</label>
<input name="checkboxes[]" value="Test" type="checkbox">
<br>
<label for="Test">TestTest:</label>
<input name="checkboxes[]" value="Test" type="checkbox">
<br>
<label for="Test">TestTestTest:</label>
<input name="checkboxes[]" value="Test" type="checkbox">
<br>
<input name="Submit" value="submit" type="submit">
</form>
```

The form has been trimmed, and fields renamed to test for posting..

In the external stylesheet, I have:

```
label {
    min-width: 5em;
}
```

The checkboxes are still not aligned. Do I have to included the stylesheet explicitly in the html of the popup window, or is it something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the popup window needs to be its own full HTML page.

---

Edit

Unless it is an AJAX popup, in which case it does NOT need to be a full HTML page.

Comment: "AJAX popup"? I'm guessing you're referring to an iframe rendered by some sort of javascript framework?

Comment: @TML - not necessarily an IFrame, could jsut be a div.  Google "AJAX Lightbox" for an example.

Comment: OK - it was just a new term to me.

Answer (score 1):

New windows don't inherit any kind of stylesheet rules from their parents.

Also, if you're using Firefox, I urge you to install the [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) extension, which will allow you to 'Inspect' an HTML element to see (and even modify) the active CSS rules.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that min-width is not supported in Internet Explorer 6. Also, I'd use some dividing element like `<div>` or `<li>` (within an `<ul>`) rather than a `<br />`.

Rich